# Identifying content displayed inside QTP

Tags: qtp

I am trying to identify the content displayed inside a frame using QTP.
I am asking from the Page all the frames that match the description and get a collection of frames.
I take the first frame from the collection but from some reason it seems that the Object doesn't exist, and therefore I can't reach the content displayed inside.
Any idea how Can I extract the content inside the frame, and why doesn't the QTP recognize it as an an existing object?
(Remark: I intentionally didn't use the repository to identify the frame cause the frame has unique location in the Page with dynamic indexes to identify its location)

Thanks,
Nathan

Code Description:

```
set TargetPage= Browser(...).Page(...)

Set objDesc = Description.Create()
objDesc("micclass").Value = "Frame"
objDesc("html id").Value = "id"
objDesc("html tag").value = "IFRAME"
objDesc("name").value = "id"

set FramesCollection = TargetPage.ChildObjects(objDesc)

Print FramesCollection .count-> Prints a number >0

set firstFrame=FramesCollection(0)
firstFrame.Exist-> Returns False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `Exist` on an object returned by `ChildObjects` for a full explanation on why this is see this [blog post](http://h30501.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/Technical-How-QTP-identifies-Objects/ba-p/10332).

You should just use the object without checking whether it exists. If you want to prove to yourself that the object is actually found correctly you can use the undocumented `Highlight` method.

Comment: The reason why Highlight is not documented is because it will let QTP hang even more often. So, use it with care and always save your work before running code with Highlight in it.